# CSS - Select specific element inside other element with same tag name and attributes

Tags: html, css

Please see the following html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar-column">
        <h2 class="title">Column 01</h2>
        <p>content01</p>
        <p>content02</p>
        <p>content03</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar-column">
        <h2 class="title">Column 02</h2>
        <p>content04</p>
        <p>content05</p>
        <p>content06</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to select only the second title  with content "Column 02" is there anyway to do that using only CSS?

I've tried many way including select the headline "h2" of the second child class "sidebar-column" but doesn't work:

```
<style>
    div.sidebar-column:nth-child(2) > h2.title {
    background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

After adding style "background-color: red", the second "h2" is supposed to change background color to red, but nothing happen.

and idea? Thanks!

Edit: I've found out how to fix the issue. Just remove the ">". The css now become:

```
  <style>
    div.sidebar-column:nth-child(2) h2.title {
    background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
```

Now it's worked in Wordpress addition CSS. But I still don't know why.

Comment: Seems like it's working? http://jsfiddle.net/qxL65wp4/5/

Comment: Your CSS selector works for me.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: If it doesn't work for you then try using `+`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a description of what you mean by "doesn't work". Others have demonstrated that the selector you are saying doesn't work does in fact select the element you want.

Comment: Edited. I added the style to additional CSS in Wordpress, but nothing happen. It's weird that it worked for everyone else. Maybe my browser? - Opera version 54.0.2952.54

Comment: Edit: I've found out how to fix the issue. Just remove the ">". The css now become:

    <style>
      div.sidebar-column:nth-child(2) h2.title {
      background-color: red;
      }
    </style>

Now it's worked in Wordpress addition CSS. But I still don't know why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Best way is just add an data-attribute to your template and select with that data-attribute in css.
working http://jsfiddle.net/Ls8EP/65/ `link`

Comment: Answers which show code on this site, rather than making people visit another site, are generally more appreciated than those which don't.

Comment: Also, the OP says in their title the elements have the same attributes. If you're going to add attributes, might as well add another class or an id and use that rather than a data- attribute, as both of those are faster.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I can't change HTML since I'm adding additional CSS to wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing it.

SOLUTION 1- make one more css class (eg-class2) and add both the classes to the second h2 element.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar-column">
        <h2 class="title">Column 01</h2>
        <p>content01</p>
        <p>content02</p>
        <p>content03</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar-column">
        <h2 class="title class2">Column 02</h2>
        <p>content04</p>
        <p>content05</p>
        <p>content06</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second class will contain the code-

```
<style>
.class2{
     background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

SOLUTION 2- Or if you just want to add red background color to `Column 02`,you can write the inline CSS code

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar-column">
            <h2 class="title">Column 01</h2>
            <p>content01</p>
            <p>content02</p>
            <p>content03</p>
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar-column">
            <h2 class="title" style="background-color:red;">Column 02</h2>
            <p>content04</p>
            <p>content05</p>
            <p>content06</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, as title I want to select element inside element with same attributes since I'm unable to edit HTML in my wordpress site.